# Replace 3-way Dimmer with Timer Switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, dimmer-switch

I have a 3 way setup, with a Dimmer Switch and a simple switch. I want to replace the Dimmer Switch with a timer switch.

The dimmer switch I'm removing has 4 wires: Black (hot), Green (ground), and two red. One red looks like it's going to a black wire in the system (load?).

The new timer switch has 4 wires as well, Black(hot), Green(ground), Red(labeled Load) and White (neutral).

How can I wire the new timer switch in place of the old dimmer switch.

House was just built last year.
Thanks!

Comment: Unless this timer is capable of being used as a 3-way switch, which I doubt from the description, you cannot use it there without disabling the other 3-way switch or getting a 3-way timer.... What other wires are in the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dimmer you are replacing is a 3-way dimmer, but the timer is a single-pole.  They both have 4 wires because the dimmer doesn't need a neutral, but the timer does (to power the timer).  You'll need to get a [3-way timer](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=3-way%20timer%20switch&tbm=shop).

Comment: Comintern, that is a single-pole timer, NOT a "2-way". ... In North America we don't use the term 2-way.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey - Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Your timer is not a 3 way switch. I believe the 2 red wires are your traveler conductors If your house was built last year there may be 1 more wire in the box as switch loops are required to have a neutral in the 2014 code. Your state may not have adopted the code so don't panic if it is not there. You need a 3 way switch timer and or some rewiring to make this work.